# What does the talmud/rabbinic writing have to say about Yeshu ha-Notzri (Jesus)?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, historical-figures, christianity

I understand that the name Jesus was not uncommon 2000 years ago, and Jewish writings about the person of historical interest to the Christian Church call him "Yeshu ha-Notzri" = "Jesus the Nazarene". I understand the Talmud talks about him. Where and what does it say?"

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47805

Comment: See Peter Schäfer's "Jesus in the Talmud"

Comment: @James Jenkins - Shafer's book is online in PDF  at Internet Archive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The claim that Jesus is mentioned in the talmud, or alluded to through a code name is not new. [This](http://www.angelfire.com/mt/talmud/jesusi.html) website goes through the sources and shows that the premise might be false.

The Jewish Press [here](http://www.jewishpress.com/indepth/opinions/is-the-talmud-anti-christian/2011/08/17/0/?print) summarizes some of the ideas in a single essay. Here's part of it:

> As it turns out, every allegation about Talmudic anti-Christian texts
>   is based on the creative deconstruction of references to various
>   sinners and alleging that these actually refer to Christian figures.
>   The deconstruction operates even when the sinner in question has a
>   completely different name, or no name.