# Do Jewish people believe that Jesus existed?

Tags: christianity

Are there any evidence in Judaism that the man Jesus son of Joseph and Mary existed and if so are there dates associated with his birth and death?

Comment: Near-duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47327/472

Comment: Are we going to have "Is there evidence of so-and-so's existence?" questions for every single person mentioned in history books? −1.

Comment: @msh210 which history books from his time mention him?

Comment: @mevaqesh, I didn't say "from his time". And I don't know the answer to your question. I also don't know why you're asking.

Comment: There was a discussion here on Mi Yodea about five years ago concerning Peter the Apostle's possible authorship of the Sabbath and Yom Tov prayer Nishmat Kol Chai. The following unverified source discusses Nishmat Kol Chai:  http://www.chabadtalk.com/forum/attachment.php3?attachmentid=1448&d=1282266929  If, as some claim, Rabbi Tam determined Peter actually did author the prayer, I think it would be fair to assume that if Peter existed, Jesus existed.

Comment: @JJLL that's an interesting diyuk and one I hadn't considered. AS far as I recall, those medrashim don't mention any years or names though (other that Shimon Hapoter) and that PDF retelling ties it to Sotah 47 which is refuted http://www.angelfire.com/mt/talmud/jesusnarr.html here.

Comment: @danno. I took quick look at your link. It looks informative and I will give it a more thorough read after Shabbat. The authenticity of parts of Josephus's historical review of Israelites is often put in question. This site https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_on_Jesus suggests that Josephus's account of Jesus is doubtful, BUT, his discussion of Jesus's brother, James, is more than likely true. So I again have to think that if James existed, so did Jesus. I never realized that there are Jews who don't believe Jesus ever existed.

Comment: @JJLL There are some non-Jewish scholars who believed he never existed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ_myth_theory admittedly this is a minority view.

Comment: @mevaqesh We could go back and forth forever on this one :). To be fair, there are people who think ALL monotheastic religion is made-up and that Moses didn't really exist. And it is an awfully large minority (if not a small majority)view given the number of pagans, atheists, agnostics, secular humanists, etc. alive today.

Comment: @msh210 I think this specific personality is intertwined enough with Judaism and half of it's history that can warrant this question being asked here. It's not like asking about Genghis Kahn.

Answer (score 1):

In Jewish texts, no, and therefore, none. While there are those who believe that the talmud mentions him, there is no real conclusive proof of that (see [here](http://www.angelfire.com/mt/talmud/jesusnarr.html) for a discussion)-- the text might be speaking of other people as the facts surrounding the man mentioned distinguish him from what the gospels say about Jesus. Other, later Judaic texts deal with the idea of Jesus and the effects of others' belief in his existence, but provide no evidence as their goal is not to prove his historicity.

Comment: sources????????

Comment: sources for the fact that he is not discussed? That's a tall order.

Comment: hefty claims demand sizable evidence.  Well, since you claimi a particular interpretation of Talmudic texts, it ought not be difficult to find commentators who agree with you. Unless of course they don't exist, in which case you would be incorrect, rather than unsourced. Hint look in R. Yechial of Paris' debate, and the Meiri.

Comment: OK, I added a link If you have references and sources that claim otherwise, you should post them as an answer to what was asked.

Comment: The article you cite engages in a whole lot of apologetics. See for example counter points here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_in_the_Talmud

Comment: @Bachrach44 yes, but those reasoned arguments are not countered textually by the claims listed on the wiki page. I cited the page not to say that there is zero claim, but that, as I wrote "no real conclusive proof" unless you think the scholars on the wiki page are making a conclusive case and are speaking from within Judaism (as the question asks). If so, you should present their material as an answer to the question asked.

Comment: I agree with this. The Jesus in the Talmud is probably not the historical Jesus (the Tos. Rosh in Sota says this as do other opinions). If it is the same person, then the world has come to believe in an idolator, sorcerer, and inciter (one who led Jews away from the Torah), as that is what a man named Yeshu is described as being.